# Project ERROR: Could not find feature framework. Qt5

Tags: ubuntu, qt5, qmake

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 Qt5.8 from scratch. I'm trying to assemble plug-in ibase. For this I did following a few steps: added in the source applications "source"

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get build-dep qt5-default
sudo apt-get install libxcb-xinerama0-dev firebird-dev firebird2.5-super ubuntu-sdk qt4-qmake libqt4-dev
ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfbclient.so /usr/lib/libgds.so
cd ~/Qt/5.8/Src/ && export QTDIR=~/Qt/5.8/Src && export PATH=$QTDIR/qtbase/bin:$PATH && cd $QTDIR/qtbase/src/plugins/sqldrivers/ibase
qmake "INCLUDEPATH+=/usr/include" "LIBS+=-L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lfbclient" ibase.pro 
Project ERROR: Could not find feature framework.
Project ERROR: Could not find feature c++11.
```

What you need to do to get rid of errors?